# analytics:reportChart not displayed when rerendered

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender, analytics, charts

I have a custom component, which contains analytics:reportChart. I need it to be displayed, when other component is loaded, but sometimes it isn't showed. Component Chart2 contains analytics:reportChart.

```
        <apex:outputPanel id="charts">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! requestSucceeded}">
            <div style="overflow-x: auto;" >
                <div class="text-center" style="display:table-cell">
                    <c:Chart1 id="chart1" chartData="{! chartData}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center" id="chart2" style="display:table-cell; width:100%">
                    <c:Chart2 id="chart2Comp"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: It's only available in API Version 29.0 and later. Are you trying to included in pages with a lower version?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm using API Version 36.0 in both/